# Camstudio: *.avi file not found: how to get past 2GB limit

Tags: android, recording

So I wanted to record my computer screen off an Android emulator and got the error that the .avi file could not be found. The reason for this is because the size of the video is over 2GB large. Does anyone know how to overcome this? My video was only like 3 minutes long and it had a size of 2.9GB, which is outrageous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer to this. The first thing I would suggest is to edit your region. I was using fullscreen before, which took a lot more memory than it should have. After going to Region -> Window to only record the window I was interested in (my Android emulator), I lowered the memory from 2.9 gigs to 20 megabytes. If that still doesn't work for you, you could try going to Options then lowering the video quality. If that still doesn't work and your video is super long, you should try using veedub. Hope this helps anyone out there.